# Ignore Notices from log file in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

How to ignore to write notices in exception and system log file, only real time critical errors should be write..

Your inputs is really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` to your index.php file.

Comment: Not Working, Still notices were generating..